# equation string in vb .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, math, calculator

I'm trying to build a scientific calculator with vb .net, except it is vista glass :-p

I basically want the user to be able to enter an equation like SQRT(5 * 6) / (2 ^ 4)  and then I want vb to use system.math to solve it. If I write this in my code, vb is able to do it, so how could I do this at runtime.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this tutorial](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/dynamicCode/DynamicCode.htm) on dynamically executing code.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody's already done this (including source code):

> http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/11/4513.aspx

Answer (score 0):

**Microsoft** have already [done](http://www.winsupersite.com/win7/ff_calc.asp) this (in Windows 7).

[Scientific mode calculator in Windows 7 http://cache.gawker.com/assets/images/17/2009/07/340x_c-scientificmode.png](http://cache.gawker.com/assets/images/17/2009/07/340x_c-scientificmode.png)

(I realize you're just doing this for fun and probably don't care.)

Answer (score 0):

There is not a simple way to do this. You can write a parser to handle the general expressions and functions (the most fun), or you can make a call to excel or an equivalent program that handles expressions.